# Spring JWT - Add custom claims

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

can you help me with my problem? I generated JWT for my client using Spring OAuth2. I have implemented an authorization and resource server along with some web security configuration, everything done with online guides.

It works fine, but now I want to edit the payload and add custom properties, for example a user's first name and last name and so on. Can you check my code and tell me what should I do for adding additional properties into payload? Thanks.

Here is my implementation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Value("${security.signing-key}")
    private String signingKey;

    @Value("${security.encoding-strength}")
    private Integer encodingStrength;

    @Value("${security.security-realm}")
    private String securityRealm;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .realmName(securityRealm)
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable();

    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey(signingKey);
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    //Making this primary to avoid any accidental duplication with another token service instance of the same name
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }
}
```

Authorization Server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Value("${security.jwt.client-id}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${security.jwt.client-secret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Value("${security.jwt.grant-type}")
    private String grantType;

    @Value("${security.jwt.scope-read}")
    private String scopeRead;

    @Value("${security.jwt.scope-write}")
    private String scopeWrite = "write";

    @Value("${security.jwt.resource-ids}")
    private String resourceIds;

    @Value("${security.jwt.expiration}")
    private int expiration;

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
        configurer
                .inMemory()
                .withClient(clientId)
                .secret(clientSecret)
                .authorizedGrantTypes(grantType)
                .scopes(scopeRead, scopeWrite)
                .resourceIds(resourceIds)
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(expiration);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        TokenEnhancerChain enhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        enhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(accessTokenConverter));
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore)
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter)
                .tokenEnhancer(enhancerChain)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
}
```

Resource server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private ResourceServerTokenServices tokenServices;

    @Value("${security.jwt.resource-ids}")
    private String resourceIds;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId(resourceIds).tokenServices(tokenServices);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .requestMatchers()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/**", "/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/springjwt/**" ).authenticated();
    }
}
```

Comment: What about implementation AuthenticationProvider?

Answer (score 8):

I had to add *iat* (issued at) claim. I implemented a custom token enhancer CustomTokenEnhancer.

```
    public class CustomTokenEnhancer implements TokenEnhancer {
        @Override
        public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {

           Map<String, Object> info = new HashMap<>();
           info.put("iat", Instant.now().getEpochSecond());
           ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(info);

           return accessToken;
        }

    }
```

Then registered the enhancer using setTokenEnhancers(). Do remember to add tokenEnhancer() as the **first in the chain**.

```
     @Bean
     public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
        return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
     }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        TokenEnhancerChain enhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();

        enhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), accessTokenConverter));
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore)
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter)
                .tokenEnhancer(enhancerChain)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager).tokenGranter(tokenGranter(endpoints));
    }
```

Comment: You don't need `.accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter)` when using `.tokenEnhancer(enhancerChain)`. The `accessTokenConverter` will only be used if no `tokenEnhancer` is specified.